# useState hook: why does setting a state with setState(prevState) execute at the end?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

why does the first one executes at last while the other one is working fine!
I used the debugger to find out where the problem was and I noticed that when the code reached the setDummy line it went to execute the rest of the component then came back to set the state variable which was set to empty string!
I would like to know why this behaves like that

I was expecting it to set the state variable with no difference between the 2 ways of set state!

*code example*

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [dummy,setDummy]=useState("First Value");
  const inputRef = useRef()
  const onClickHandler = () => {
    // Executes at last
    setDummy (()=> inputRef.current.value)

    // but this executes as expected 
    //setDummy(inputRef.current.value)

    inputRef.current.value = "";
  }
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <input ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>OK</button>
      <p>The variable now is: {dummy}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: setting state is async in react. so when you use either `setDummy (()=> inputRef.current.value)` or `setDummy(inputRef.current.value)`, state will get update on the next tick(after running then sync code)

Comment: @DecPK Now I get it, Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Hi maybe it should be related to the fact that as is designed in your app, setDummy is defined as a simple setter that accept as its parameter a string, not an anonymous function giving a string...I don't know if I've been clear.

Comment: I don't get it, Could you elaborate with code example ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanOsamaAhmedMohame you defined setDummy here const [dummy,setDummy]=useState("First Value"); where it accepts a string, not a function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).